# How to link the definition of sub sigma algebra to the notation $X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I am reading a paper. It says

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},P)$ be a probability space and $(\Omega_X, \mathcal{F}_X)$ be measurable spaces. Let $X$ be random elements that take values in $\Omega_X$ with distributions $P_X$, which is dominated by $\sigma-$ finite measures. Let

$$\sigma(X)=X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X),$$

and finally let $P_{Y|X}(\cdot | \cdot): \mathcal{F}_Y \times \Omega_X \to \mathbb{R}$ be the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$.

How to interpret $\sigma(X)=X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X)$? **I don't understand the notation**  $X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X)$.

The $\sigma(X)$ is the sub $\sigma$ field generated by $X$, that is $\sigma(X)=X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X)$.

From Wiki, it says Let $X$ be a set. Let $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ be $\sigma$ algebras on $X$. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is said to be a sub $\sigma$ algebra of $\mathcal{A}$ if and only if $\mathcal{B} \subset \mathcal{A}$. It's hard for me to link this definition to the notation $X^{-1} (\mathcal{F}_X)$.

Another question is how to interpret "$P_X$, which is dominated by $\sigma-$ finite measures"?

Comment: I'm familiar with this notation when we speak about random variable, namely [$\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/312474/what-is-it-meant-with-the-sigma-algebra-generated-by-a-random-variable)

Comment: @TurquoiseTilt thanks. Another question is how to interpret "$P_X$, which is dominated by $\sigma-$ finite measures"?

Comment: My guess would be that since we have a probability space over $\Omega_X$ by definition $\Omega_X$ is $\sigma$-finite and so $P_X$ as a measurable function could be dominated by some $L^1$ function and use the dominated convergence theorem. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with this notation, what's the title of the paper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The meaning of the notation is:
$$X^{-1}(\mathcal{F}_X)=\{X^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal{F}_X\}$$
That is, it consists of all the inverse images under $X$ of the sets in $\mathcal{F}_X$.

It is a $\sigma$-field because $\mathcal{F}_X$ is a $\sigma$-field and inverse images of sets preserve unions, intersections, and complements, and it is a sub $\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$ because even though the authors haven't made it entirely clear, when they use the term "random elements" and talk about $X$ having a distribution $P_X$, they mean that $X$ is a measurable function from $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ to $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ and so, by definition, $X^{-1}(B) \in \mathcal{F}$ for all $B\in\mathcal{F}_X$.

It is standard to refer to this as the $\sigma$-field generated by the random variable $X$ and to denote it $\sigma(X)$.

If you are unfamiliar with the formal measure-theoretic treatment of probability, you should try to get up to speed before trying to read the rest of this paper, but intuitively, $\sigma$-fields represent knowledge about the state of a probabilistic system.  The "big" $\sigma$-field $\mathcal{F}$ for the whole probability space represents complete knowledge about the system, and $\sigma(X)$ represents knowledge about the value of the random variable $X$ within that system.

A measure $\mu$ dominates another measure $\nu$ (written $\nu \ll \mu$) if $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\nu(A)=0$ for all $A$, and a measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite if there's a countable intersection of sets that covers the space where each set has finite $\mu$-measures.  In probability, when a distribution measure is dominated by a $\sigma$-finite measure like, say, the Lebesgue measure on the reals, then it has a density with respect to that measures.  (In simpler treatments of probability, we call the distributions that are dominated by the Lebesgue measure the "continuous" distributions and the distributions that are dominated by the counting measure the "discrete" distributions.)

In the above text, the authors are considering a collection of random variables $X$, each taking values on a measurable space $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ and having distribution $P_X\colon \mathcal{F}_X\to[0,1]$  defined by $P_X(B)=P(X^{-1}(B))$ such that $P_X$ is dominated by some a $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu_X\colon \mathcal{F}_X\to\mathbb{R}$.  The existence of these dominating measure is a vacuous assumption, since $P_X$ is already $\sigma$-finite and dominates itself.  The assumption would make sense if the authors were talking about multiple random variables defined on a *single* measurable space $(U,\mathcal{G})$ and wanted to dominate all their distribution measures by a single $\sigma$-finite measure $\mu\colon\mathcal{G}\to\mathbb{R}$, but as far as I can tell, that's not what they are saying.  I found a similar paper by the same authors, and they don't use this condition for any purpose, so it's pretty safe to ignore it.

Elsewhere in the paper, the authors might talk about a *collection* of distribution measures, all defined on the same space, being dominated by a single $\sigma$-finite measures.  That's an actual substantive assumption.

Comment: What's the relationship between probability space $\Omega$ and measurable space $\Omega_X$? And $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}_X$?

Comment: The formal definition of an $A$-valued random variable is a measurable function $X\colon\Omega\to A$ from a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ to a measurable space $(A,\mathcal{A})$.  (For real-valued $X$, we usually take $(A,\mathcal{A})=(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}))$ where $B(\mathbb{R})$ is the class of Borel sets.)  The notation in this paper is a little confusing because they've written the "destination" space as $(\Omega_X,\mathcal{F}_X)$ which makes it looks like it's supposed to be another probability space or something, but it's just the measurable space where $X$ takes values.